# Trying to make a habbo retro but there's an issue

Tags: mysql, xampp

I did everything that a guy did on YouTube, and it seemed to work perfectly so far but at the end, after I typed in "localhost", I was left with this. MySQL Engine - RevCMS: 
MySQL could not connect to database

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but this is my config (located in xampp/htdogs/app/management/

```
<?php
if(!defined('IN_INDEX')) { die('Sorry, you cannot access this file.'); }
#Please fill this all out.

#NOTE: To set up TheHabbos.ORG's API go to wwwroot/mysite/thehabbos_api for IIS, OR, htdocs/thehabbos_api for XAMPP and others.

/*
*
*   MySQL management
*
*/

$_CONFIG['mysql']['connection_type'] = 'connect'; //Type of connection: It must be connect, or pconnect: if you want a persistent connection.

$_CONFIG['mysql']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; //MySQL host

$_CONFIG['mysql']['username'] = 'root'; //MySQL username

$_CONFIG['mysql']['password'] = 'lol'; //MySQL password

$_CONFIG['mysql']['database'] = 'retro'; //MySQL database

$_CONFIG['mysql']['port'] = '3306'; //MySQL's port

/*
*
*   Hotel management  - All URLs do not end with an "/"
*
*/

$_CONFIG['hotel']['server_ip'] = 'localhost'; //IP of VPS/DEDI/etc

$_CONFIG['hotel']['url'] = 'http://localhost'; //Does not end with a "/"

$_CONFIG['hotel']['name'] = 'Habbzah'; // Hotel's name

$_CONFIG['hotel']['desc'] = 'Welcome To Habbzah Hotel!'; //Hotel's description 

$_CONFIG['hotel']['email'] = 'support@habbzah.co; //Where the help queries from users are emailed to.@Priv skin

$_CONFIG['hotel']['in_maint'] =  false; //False if hotel is NOT in maintenance. True if hotel IS in maintenance

$_CONFIG['hotel']['motto'] = 'I <3 ' . $_CONFIG['hotel']['name']; //Default motto users will register with.

$_CONFIG['hotel']['credits'] = 75000; //Default number of credits users will register with.

$_CONFIG['hotel']['pixels'] = 10000; //Default number of pixels users will register with.

$_CONFIG['hotel']['figure'] = 'ch-210-62.hd-180-1.lg-270-64.hr-100-31.sh-290-62'; //Default figure users will register with.

$_CONFIG['hotel']['web_build'] = '63_1dc60c6d6ea6e089c6893ab4e0541ee0/1013'; //Web_Build

$_CONFIG['hotel']['external_vars'] = 'http://localhost/r63/external_variables.txt'; //URL to your external vars

$_CONFIG['hotel']['external_texts'] = 'http://localhost/r63/external_flash_texts.txt'; //URL to your external texts

$_CONFIG['hotel']['product_data'] = 'http://localhost/r63/productdata.txt'; //URL to your productdata

$_CONFIG['hotel']['furni_data'] = 'http://localhost/r63/furnidata.txt'; //URL to your furnidata

$_CONFIG['hotel']['swf_folder'] = 'http://localhost/r63'; //URL to your SWF folder(does not end with a '/')
/*
*
*   Templating management - Pick one of our default styles or make yours by following our examples!
*
*/

#RevCMS has 2 default styles, 'Mango' by dannyy94 and 'Priv' by joopie - Others styles are to come, such as RastaLulz's ProCMS style and Nominal's PhoenixCMS 4.0 style.

$_CONFIG['template']['style'] = 'DahT3H'; 

/*
*
*   Other topsites.. thing
*
*/

$_CONFIG['thehabbos']['username'] = 'Jynx';
$_CONFIG['retro_top']['user'] = 'Jynx'; 

/*
*
*   Recaptcha management - Fill the information below if you have one, else leave it like that and don't worry, be happy.
*
*/

$_CONFIG['recaptcha']['priv_key'] = '6LcZ58USAAAAABSV5px9XZlzvIPaBOGA6rQP2G43';
$_CONFIG['recaptcha']['pub_key'] = '6LcZ58USAAAAAAQ6kquItHl4JuTBWs-5cSKzh6DD';


/*
*
*   Social Networking stuff
*
*/

$_CONFIG['social']['twitter'] = 'TwitterAccount'; //Hotel's Twitter account

$_CONFIG['social']['facebook'] = 'FacebookAccount'; //Hotel's Facebook account


?>
```

I don't understand, I even asked for help from them, they told me to change the password, I did that but there was no change!

Comment: These Habbo retro scripts are bad scripted and too messy, you can't easily find issues on it. Try instead of `localhost` this `127.0.0.1`. *Edit: You know `Sulake` won't be happy if they see you with a retro hotel..?

Comment: Well.. A lot of kids are making them these days o3o, but thanks.